# DNS entry for a domain name that resides online

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

I am trying to create a DNS entry on a local DNS server to do a lookup for a domain name that resides online.

The problem is that the domain name is local.example.com and the DNS entry I am trying to lookup is `cloud.example.com`

When I type the address in the search bar, the DNS cannot be resolved because the local DNS server does not have that entry locally. However when I use a public DNS like `4.2.2.2.2` I am able to reach this address. I tried to make a AAA entry for this domain name on the local server but it made no difference.

Anyone have any idea what time doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that you want to make a local entry to fix something locally by altering how your internal DNS server responds to an external query.

You said that you have `local.example.com` in your internal DNS. But you want to change `cloud.example.com`. To do this you'd need to add a zone for example.com, and add that record there. This of course means that your local DNS server thinks that the whole zone is local, so you need to replicate every record in that zone for those to work as well.

Depending on your DNS server software (Microsoft DNS, PowerDNS, bind9, etc.) there's some other workarounds that are less invasive.

If it's only a single host (for example, you're testing a new application, and want to change DNS for those who are testing it, but not everybody) it's a lot easier to just change the hosts file on your computer.

For Windows you'll need to add a line like this to `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`

```
192.0.2.44 cloud.example.com
```